# Reapplying past normalization from keras.utils.normalize

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, normalization

I used tf.keras.utils.normalize to normalize my trainingdata from a large dataset.

```
a = tf.keras.utils.normalize(a, axis=-1)
```

I am now done with training and want to apply the model to real data.
However now I need some way of applying the exact same normalization to the non-test data as well.
How do I read the function performed by utils.normalize or ensure re-appliance to a new dataset ?

Comment: `tf.keras.utils.normalize` is different from `StandardScaler()`,`MinMaxScaler()` and other parameter normalization. It uses [`np.linalg.norm()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) to achieve L2-normalization, which the sum of squared of elements would be equal to one.  You can't apply it to the other set because there are no parameters.

Comment: This means all values of array a before normalization are divided by the same number to get the normalized value. Therefore I can simply extract that divisor by dividing a normalized number by its non-normalized counterpart. This solves it; thx.

Comment: The array are divided by the different number to get the normalized value based on `axis`. You can't simply extract that divisor by dividing a normalized number by its non-normalized counterpart.

Comment: Example of non-normalized (left) and normalized data (right): {1.1943, 0.0952761920724838},{1.1153, 0.0889739069065069},{1.142, 0.0911039197410839}. You will find that dividing left by right will always yield the same number (if the same dataset is used). Therefore if the Network is trained on these numbers I should be able to multiply the new data with the common number to yield data that will be usable by the trained network.

Comment: The same `axis` will be divided by the same number, but different `axis` will be divided by different numbers, so I said `The array are divided by the different number to get the normalized value based on axis`. You can test 2d array to see the result.

Comment: So [0,0] and [0,1] have same divisor, but [1,0] and [1,1] have not ?

Comment: Suppose your `a` is `[[0,3,4],[2,6,4]]`. You will get the result of `tf.keras.utils.normalize(a, axis=-1)` is `[[0.,0.6,0.8],[0.26726124,0.80178373,0.53452248]]`. You can see that the divisor of the first row is `5`, but the divisor of the second row is `7.48331477`.

Comment: So my network will be totally fine with new data if I just use utils.normalize on it again ? - Assuming same Array-Layout as training-data.

Comment: If you are using `utils.normalize`, my answer is yes.

Comment: Excellent. This makes utils.normalize even more useful than I thought.

Comment: But I don't recommend you to use `utils.normalize`. You will easily find that the normalized results of `[[0,3,4],[2,6,4]]` and `[[0,30,40],[20,60,40]]` are the same.